# Extract text data from a encrypted .DAT file of a game

Tags: decryption

I want to read a text .DAT file, but it's "encrypted". The file is from the a smartphone game. There are several .dat files stored on the smartphone, I would like to decode them to know the dates of the events in the game etc.

The files are on .dat & do xx ko, i don't found how i can open it good. I test open with libre calc, word, notepad++, sublim text, 7zip etc.

When i open it with notepad++ i have this :
[image]

A link of the .dat file : https://easyupload.io/gc967e

Please can you help me find a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: was anyone able to figure this out? im also trying to edit a game i love playing

Comment: I would suggest RE the game, instead of this DAT file.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ returns this illegible mess because the file is not meant to be interpreted as human-readable text. That doesn't necessarily mean it's encrypted (but that's a possibility).

I'm assuming that it's a savegame file and you are probably looking to change some value (like the amount of money your character has). You could try opening this file in a hex editor (I like [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/)). That way you will be able to read some values from this file instead of getting those weird symbols you get in N++.

Furthermore you should read up on endianness and encoding to better understand what you are seeing.

Comment: I am not trying to cheat I like this game a lot and I do not want to take any interest away from it by cheating. But I understand better why the files are not easily readable (in fact it makes sense). But I don't say the name of the game, it's not for nothing.

I love this game and my goal is just to know about future events to better save my resources when needed.

Comment: I already tried HxD to see if there were magic bits (to know the file format) but it doesn't work.
I tested your software online it is the same result, understandable series of characters.

I saw on another topic a software to find in which language it is encrypted, but I am not able to use it (not enough knowledge in programming).

Excellent XorSearch tool by Didier Stevens: https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/xorsearch/